# Which process is running a certain window in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 and some things are done differently. I would like to know how I can find the process associated with a particular window. On Windows 7, this was trivial: in Task Manager, you select the name of the listed window and then you right-click and select "go to process". This doesn't seem to be available on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have clicked 'More details'.

The option is now called "Go to details" (visible when 'More details' has been used to expand Task Manager).